# Meaning of ? in Map<String, ?>

Tags: java, generics, collections

Method `createBuilderFactory` in `javax.json` needs argument of type `Map<String, ?>`

Generally, we have map with like `Map<String, String>`(some other data types in place of `String`)

But I didn't understand what does `?` stands for. And in order to pass argument of type `Map<String, ?>`, how I should define the map.

Can someone please help me to understand this better?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In Java generics the `?` stands for wildcard, which represent any object.**

If you create a method that takes `Map<String, ?>` you are saying that you expect a `Map` that maps from `String` keys to any possible object values:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Object> map1 = null;
    Map<String, String> map2 = null;

    test(map1);
    test(map2);
}

private static void test(Map<String, ?> settings) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had difficulties when I need to pass `Map<String, ?>` to my function, which was accepting `Map<String, Object>`. And this cut it:

```
Map<String, ?> mapQuestion = ...
mapObject = (Map<String, Object>)mapQuestion;
```